# How to click button "Save Configuration" after click button "Apply" in AppleScript

Tags: user-interface, applescript

How can I click button "Save Configuration" after click button "Apply" for save my VPN configuration in AppleScript on MacOs 10.11.

[image]

I tried:

```
click button "Apply" of window 1
click button "Save Configuration" of window 1
```

But command click button "Save Configuration" is not get it. Anyone has idea about it.

Thank you.

Comment: I've got half your problem worked out, I think, but the rest depends on you telling me when you get that "Save Configuration" dialog; I haven't been able to get that to come up. For me, I can click on the Apply button by this (note that less wordy versions of this code don't seem to work, so try with this exact code.) `tell application "System Events"
 tell application "System Preferences"
  tell «class butT» "Apply" of window "Network" of «class pcap» "System Preferences" of application "System Events" to click
 end tell
end tell`

Comment: - do you already have the Apply button click working?

Comment: Yes, Apply button is working

Comment: I configured VPN with PPTP protocol, and after click button apply, "Save configuration" dialog pop up and I click button "Save Configuration", but it's not work. I also inspect elements and i know that parent element of button "Save Configuration" is NULL(You can see above image)

Comment: Ok. Sorry about that. The problem is I never get that Save config window.

Comment: Is command-s mapped to that button? Try it. When the dialog comes up, hit command-s and see if it activates the button. Then you might be able to use System Events to do the keystroke - perhaps after a small delay.